# How to approximate with integrals?

Tags: integration, probability-theory, inequality

Let $n$ be a positive integer and $j=1,2,\ldots, n;$ then I found in an article saying that by using approximations by integrals it is easy to show that
$$
\frac{j}{n+1}<1-e^{-(\frac{1}{n}+\cdots + \frac{1}{n-j+1})}<\frac{j}{n+\frac{1}{2}}
$$

But I do not see that this is easy and don't know how to use the integral approximations. Any help would be great to proceed further.

Thanks!

Comment: What article is this from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing elementary manipulations the inequalities can be written as
$$
\log\frac{n+1}{n-j+1}<\frac{1}{n-j+1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}<\log\frac{n+1/2}{n-j+1/2}.
$$
Considering that $\log\frac{a}{b}=\log a-\log b=\int_a^b\frac{dx}{x}$ it seems like a good idea to express this as
$$
\int_{n-j+1}^{n+1}\frac{dx}{x}<\frac{1}{n-j+1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}<\int_{n-j+1/2}^{n+1/2}\frac{dx}{x}.
$$
We have only reworded the problem, but now it becomes obvious if we think in terms of *Riemann sums*;

[image]

[image]

Comment: @SimpleArt I think you will find this pleasingly familiar ;)

Comment: Wow! Thanks, but it is not easy as the authors claimed.